# Underscores in method names [silly mistake]

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.2

EDIT: My mistake - there was another method name (with the underscore) at another place which had only a pass in its body. Stupid me. Please close.

I have a class with two methods, each returning a simple string. The only slightly qualitative difference between these two methods is that one has an underscore in its name while the other doesn't. However, the one with the underscore does not return the string when called. Using underscores in names of methods seems to follow [PEP 8 guidelines regarding method names](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).

I have been reading the [Python tutorial on classes](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) thoroughly but it doesn't mention any difference in behaviour depending use of underscore inside the method name. If I remove the underscore, the string will be returned.

What's causing this?

Here's my code:

```
class Board:
    def f(self):
        return 'Hello'
    def print_board(self):
        return 'Hello'
```

I'm using Python 3.2.3.

Comment: Can you post a full program demonstrating this?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with this code. Calling both methods works as expected.

Comment: Sorry - found out I had another method with the same name but without any code to execute. Apologies for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me with Python 3.2.1 and 3.3.0:

```
class Board:
    def f(self):
        return 'Hello'
    def print_board(self):
        return 'Hello'


b = Board()
print(b.f())
print(b.print_board())
```

Executed at Windows, it prints:

```
c:\tmp\_Python>c:/python32/python a.py
Hello
Hello

c:\tmp\_Python>c:/python33/python a.py
Hello
Hello
```

Possibly you wanted to write:

```
...
    def print_board(self):
        print('Hello')
```

and call it

```
...
b.print_board()
```

Comment: See my edit - it was just a silly mistake, I had another (but empty) method with that same name. I was staring myself blind at testing the wrong part of the class.

Comment: I see. For such cases, pylint tool may be usefull. The following one is the on-line version http://antares.sip.ucm.es/cesar/pylint/. It finds also duplicities in function definitions.

Comment: Not quite sure whether I should accept the answer or not, ended up accepting it. Given that the question from the beginning was regarding a non-existent problem, I guess it should be deemed a good answer :)

Comment: If it is not clear if yes or no, then it probably does not matter :) The main goal is to solve the problem, isn't it? I am not doing it for collecting points, but thanks ;)